# Probability that the picked hand will have at least one sequence in a game of Rummy with two standard decks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**QUESTION:**

The game of Rummy is usually played with two standard decks of cards each containing 52 cards.Both of the deck contain four suits -hearts(h), diamond(d),club(c) and spade(s) comprising of 13 cards each. In the game, each player is dealt with 13 cards . The is to arrange these cards in valid sets and sequences.

$\textbf{Set: }$A set is a group of three or more cards of the same value but of different suits, e.g.

1. A-h,A-s,A-c
2. 8-s,8-d,8-c,8-h

$\textbf{Note: }$Sets like 3-h, 3-h, 3-d are invalid because the two '3' are of same suit.

$\textbf{Sequence : }$A sequence is a group of three or more cards of the same suit, placed in consecutive order e.g.

1. 5-h,6-h,7-h
2. J-s,Q-s,K-s,A-s
3. A-d,2-d,3-d

$\textbf{Note: }$Ace card can form a sequence with both 2 and King card. However, a sequence like K-d,A-d,2-d is invalid.

**On the basis of the above information,calculate the following.

1. Number of distinct ways in which you can pick 13 cards from 2 decks of cards.

2. Probability that the picked hand will have at least one sequence.**

**My solution:**

I am able to find the solution of first question only. and the solution is as follows:

Since there are 2 decks of cards, so total number of cards are 104. There is exactly one pair \ of each card i.e, 2 cards of 5-h, 2 cards of A-d etc. So, there is 52 distinct pairs.

[image]

Number of ways of choosing a card from given pair is only 1 i.e. 2-h,2-h are identical and total number of ways of choosing one card from 2-h, 2-h is only one.

Number of distinct ways to pick 13 cards from 2 decks :

We split the ways into different cases:

Case1 :

All 13 cards are distinct

We have 52 identical pairs, so we can select 13 distinct cards in $\displaystyle \binom{52}{13}$

Case2:

Two alike cards and 11 distinct cards, so we can select in $\displaystyle \binom{52}{1}\binom{51}{11}$, where $\displaystyle \binom{52}{1}$ are ways of choosing a pair and $\displaystyle \binom{51}{11}$ are ways of choosing 11 distinct cards.

Case 3 :

Two alike cards of one kind and other two alike cards of different kind, so possible ways

$\displaystyle \binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{9}$

And so on ....

So the total number of distinct ways to pick 13 cards are :

$$\displaystyle =\binom{52}{13}\binom{52}{1}\binom{51}{11}\binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{9}\binom{52}{3}\binom{49}{7}\binom{52}{4}\binom{48}{5}\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{3}\binom{52}{6}\binom{46}{1}$$

I don't how to solve the solve the second question: Probability that the picked hand will have at least one sequence.

**Can anyone give me a hint , what should be my approach to solve it?**

Comment: For the 1st question, since the cases are disjoint (i.e. not overlapping) and their union is what you're counting, you need to add the cases, not multiply them.  I.e. ${52 \choose 13} + {52 \choose 1} {51 \choose 11} + {52 \choose 2} {50 \choose 9} + \dots$  I don't think the 2nd question can be answered without a very tedious case analysis.  You can condition on the number $K$ of distinct cards, where $7 \le K \le 13$ and (i) find $P(K=k)$ and then (ii) $P(\exists sequence | K=k)$, but it's very tedious.